# Laravel cloning query string

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to clone a query string so I can write it once and make alterations a long the way without affection other results?

```
$query = DB::table('users')
         ->where('id', '=', '123');

$queryGet = $query;
$queryPaginate = $query;
$queryCount = $query;

if(Input::has('get'))
  $queryGet = $queryGet->get();

if(Input::has('paginate'))
  $queryPaginate = $queryPaginate->paginate(25);

if(Input::has('count'))
  $queryCount = $queryCount->count(DB::raw('Distinct users.*'));
```

Because right now, the paginate will alter the first get().

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You had the vocabulary exactly right :) In PHP5+, try cloning:

```
<?php
$queryGet = clone $query;
$queryPaginate = clone $query;
$queryCount = clone $query;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php

Comment: Addition: in new PHP versions you may also use the cloned query objects directly, without having to store an intermediate state.  

For example: `$queryPaginate = (clone $query)->paginate(25);`

Comment: Nice, thanks!  I see that it is possible to do `$query->clone()` in Laravel 9. Earlier versions might have it. Not sure when it was added.

Answer (score 6):

Mopo922 answer is the right way to do this on Laravel >= 4.1. But, in previous versions, the query doesn't "deep clone", and would produce unexpected results, as the main query is stored in a child `Query` object, not in the mail `Builder`.

To avoid this bug, you can use:

```
$newClone = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder(clone $builder->getQuery());
```

You can see this bug/fix story on: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1336