# Laravel method all and select not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code:

```
$orders = Order::all();
$allorders = $orders->count();
$deliveryQuery = $orders->where('status', '=', '8')->select(DB::raw('AVG(updated_at) as order_average'))->first();
```

I get error:

`Method select does not exist.`

How I can fix it? My code is working, if I do:

```
$deliveryQuery = Order::where('status', '=', '8')->select(DB::raw('AVG(updated_at) as order_average'))->first();
```

But this not good, I want 1 query, but not 2..

**UPDATE:**

```
$orders->where('status', '=', '8')->avg('updated_at')->first();
```

I can use this code? But it not working..Get error:

`Object of class Illuminate\Support\Carbon could not be converted to int`

Comment: What's wrong with the second way?

Comment: extra query I do..

Comment: `$orders = Order::all();` return a collection that's why you can't query on that.

Comment: You're confusing `collection` methods with query builder. You're trying to do 2nd SQL call in your first attempt (by using `->select()`, which is a query builder method) but calling it on a Laravel collection.

Comment: How I can fix it?

Comment: You can't do a select after get records from eloquent modal.

Comment: Please see updated question..

Comment: If you are using laravel 5.5, you can use `withCount` method

Comment: Why you are using AVG on time?? What is your objective ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this..

```
$query = Order::query();
$orders = clone $query;

$orders = $orders->all();
$allorders = $orders->count();

$deliveryQuery = $query->where('status', '=', '8')->select(DB::raw('AVG(updated_at) as order_average'))->first();
```

similar question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27625411/laravel-cloning-query-string)

Answer (score 1):

The all() method return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections). You can then use Collection [methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) on the result, but where() and select() are methods of the [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) class.

```
$query = Order::query(); // You can get the query builder this way.

$orders = Order::all(); // equivalent to $query->get(); => return a Collection

$orderCount = Order::count(); // equivalent to $query->count();
$orderCount = $orders->count(); // here $orders is a Collection and the count() method is from the Collection class
```

When you call avg(), you're calling it from the Collection class. But it can only work on number, and updated_at attribute is parsed to a Carbon date by Laravel.

Your code could be :

```
$query = Order::query();
$orders = $query->get();
$allorders = $query->count();
$deliveryQuery = $query->where('status', '=', '8')->select(DB::raw('AVG(updated_at) as order_average'))->first();
```

Comment: ``"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()"``

Comment: Have you applied global scopes to your Order class ? If so, use $query->withoutGlobalScopes()->get();